# He/she(singular) replaces with they(plural) in one sentence

Tags: grammar

How does ‘they(plural)’ replace with singular’(he/she)’ in a sentence?
Example: If he or she doesn’t want to do it then it’s their wish.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, *they* is a gender-neutral pronoun. It's called *[singular they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they)*. It can be used when you don't know the gender of the person you are talking about. It can be used in any position in a sentence.

> A journalist should not be forced to reveal **their** sources.

> If Sally or George got a cold, I would have sympathy for **them**.

> Each student submitted **their** art portfolio to the committee.

Note that grammatically, it's still treated as a plural pronoun, so it always takes a plural verb.

> Every individual is unique. **They** *are* a combination of strengths and weaknesses.

> Every student has what **they** *need* to succeed.

The only difference between the singular *they* and the normal plural *they* is that the former has two *self* forms, *themselves* and *themself*.

From [Lexico](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825043531/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/themselves-or-themself):

> In recent years, people have started to use *themself* to correspond to this singular use of *they* and *them*: it’s seen as the logical singular form of *themselves*. For example:

> > This is the first step in helping someone to help **themself**.

> This form is not yet widely accepted, though, so you should avoid using it in formal written contexts. If you were writing the sentence above, you should say:

> > This is the first step in helping someone to help **themselves**.